# What does $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \in \mathbb{R}^{d'}$ mean?

Tags: notation

In this [MSR Technical Report](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=155552), I came across a definition of the manifold learning problem:

> Given a set of $k$ unlabelled observations
>   $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k\}$ with $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we wish
>   to find a smooth mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \in \mathbb{R}^{d'}$,
>   $f(v_i) = v_i'$ such that $d' << d$ and that preserves the
>   observations' relative geodesic distances.

I understand the notation $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d'}$ ; what's the significance of $\in$?

Comment: do you have any reason to believe this isn't a typo?

Comment: @Jonathan: I suspect it was caused when one of the authors wanted to copy-paste $\mathbb{R}^{d'}$ from something like $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d'}$ and accidentally copy-pasted $\in \mathbb{R}^{d'}$.

Comment: From my familiarity with the subject I can say it is almost certainly a typo and you can ignore it. f simply maps to vectors of a much lower dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community verdict: there are typos in the box on page 97.

- $\mathbf v_i\in\mathbf{R}^d$ should read $\mathbf v_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$
- $\mathbf f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \in\mathbb{R}^{d'}$ should read $\mathbf f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^{d'}$.